# How to wirte Public Dialog addClickListener write back Form TextField

Tags: vaadin14

I’m a beginner, I can’t pass this level, please help.

I have a lot of forms with TextField (cust_no, cust_name), each with a button on the right,

press the button
A dialog can be display custom record, after selecting the required customer,
Write the selected cust_no, cust_name back to the Text_Field of Form.

I hope to write dialog as a public class, so that many class Forms can use this function, and can also smoothly write cust_no and cust_name back to their respective Form TextField.

In addition to backfilling cust_no,cust_name TextField for some Forms, some also need to query the consumption amount and write back the specified cust_amt TextField.

My trouble is that form button.addClickListener open a dialog,
Dialog’s Button_OK.addClickListener cannot know how I want to write back Form TextField and some have special query mechanisms, how to customize

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing exactly how your code is structured, I can only give a quite generic answer. What you need is typically that something associated with the button for opening the dialog can know what to do with the result from the dialog, and it can also configure the dialog's OK button to carry out that action.

```java
public class HelloWorldView extends VerticalLayout {
    public HelloWorldView() {
        TextField customerNumberField = new TextField("Customer number");
        TextField customerNameField = new TextField("Customer name");
        Button nameDialogButton = new Button("Open dialog", dialogOpenClick -> {
            showDialog(customer -> {
                customerNumberField.setValue(customer.getNumber());
                customerNameField.setValue(customer.getName());
            });
        });

        add(customerNumberField, customerNameField, nameDialogButton);
    }

    private void showDialog(Consumer<Customer> selectionAction) {
        Select<Customer> customerSelect = new Select<>(new Customer("1", "Customer 1"),
                new Customer("2", "Customer 2"));
        customerSelect.setTextRenderer(customer -> customer.getName());

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.add(customerSelect);
        dialog.add(new Button("Select customer", click -> {
            Customer selectedCustomer = customerSelect.getValue();
            if (selectedCustomer != null) {
                selectionAction.accept(selectedCustomer);
            }
            dialog.close();
        }));

        dialog.open();
    }
}
```